# flatMap, flat, flatten doesn't exist on type any[]

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Chrome 70 and Chrome does add methods `.flatMap`, `.flatten`, `.flat`. So my code does run as expected. Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't like it.

```
// data.flatMap lint error
export const transformData = (data: any[]) => data.flatMap(abc => [
   parentObj(abc),
   ...generateTasks(abc)
]);
```

The warning I got is `TS2339: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

I'm using Angular 6, which uses Typescript ~2.9.2, and I already include `import 'core-js/es7/array';` in `polyfills.ts`.

My guess is that there is no typing for these methods, and I did try to `npm run -dev @types/array.prototype.flatmap` but still not solve.

Answer (score 563, accepted):

You should add `es2019` or `es2019.array` to your `--lib` setting for TypeScript to recognize `array.flat()` and `flatMap()`.

Example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  }
}
```

Previously this was available as part of `esnext` or `esnext.array`, but it's now officially part of ES2019.

Comment: Yup I reproduce this and it works. Here my `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.app.json`  `"lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext.array",
    ]`

Thank you sir

Comment: This did not fix it for me in my IDE, VSCode. Any tips?

Comment: @timelf123 did you restart your IDE?

Comment: Is there a reason (and if so what's the effect) of using `"esnext"` instead of `"esnext.array"`?

Comment: @maninak `"esnext"` just includes [additional stuff](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.esnext.d.ts) besides the array proposals.

Comment: Replacing esnext, esnext.array or es2017 with es2019 got it to work for me.

Comment: @BlairZajac Yep, Array stuff is officially part of ES2019 now, so I updated the answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note: flatMap is now supported in node 11+

Comment: @Onza It should work, the problem is likely in your build configuration not properly using your tsconfig, as the default settings don't allow flat at this time.

Comment: Nope, double checked, this is on VScode; all the other configurations seem to have an effect but this one, I have absolutely no clue, the solution of Frenton does work however; either way, I just ended up deciding not to use the method.

Comment: I think commenting under accepted answer will be more efficient. getting an error: property flat does not exist on type string[][];
shouldn't be flat of type any[] still work with string[][]. I don't know how to structure well this statement.

Comment: @maninak `es2019.array` is in most cases preferred as it explicitly specifies the features of the `es2019` spec that are supported in the project which avoids accidentally using `es2019` features not supported

Comment: is there a way to add all the esXXXX years?

Comment: Worked for me to change tsconfig.json files from "lib": ["es2018"] to "lib": ["es2019"].

Comment: Thank you, it unexpectedly and surprisingly well worked for me right away. Intellij idea was able to catch up flatMap and flat RIGHT after I added libs (I already had target:es5 configured). Usually, the process is harder.... 

Comment: This works technically but the typings are terrible. `T` will be of type `S | Array<S>` basically, so `flat` is not of type `Array<T>`, but fo type `Array<S>` where S is the nested structure. I think you need to add a generic like `interface Array<T, S = any> { flat(): Array<S> }` or find a way to filter out array types from T.

Comment: Just to add , VSC needs restarted

Answer (score 39):

If you're are in a lower version than es2019, you can implement a shim to provide similar functionality to `.flat()` and `.flatMap()` provided by later libraries.

To flat single level array

```
arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
```

To flat multi level array

```
function flatDeep(arr, d = 1) {
   return d > 0 ? arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatDeep(val, d - 1) : val), []) : arr.slice();
};
```

to know deeply you can also check below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Thanks for this snippet — it was helpful as I still couldn't use `.flat()` even with the Typescript fix in the accepted answer.

Comment: This snippet helped as I still couldn't get `.flat()` to work after adding `"lib": ["ES2019"],` in tsconfig.json

Comment: be careful with `concat()` since it's a [copying method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#description). Use `push()` instead which is a [mutating method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 21):

Aaron Beall's answer is excellent. It may be worth knowing that if "lib"  is not specified in the tsConfig.JSON file a default list of libraries are injected. The default libraries injected are:
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

In other words: We must specify those libs that were previously added automatically. (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html for further info)

```
"compilerOptions": {

   "target": "es6",

   "lib": [ "es2019", "DOM", "ES6" ,"DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost"],}
```

Answer (score 8):

I tried most answers and they didn't work for me.
IDE: VScode

but this did

```sh
npm i -D @types/node
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the global array interface while you wait for stability, at which point it will be added to the default library.

```
interface Array<T> {
    flat(): Array<T>;
    flatMap(func: (x: T) => T): Array<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of angular 11 and thx to [typescript 3.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html) this is now the new config.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
}
```

#### Why `es2020` instead of `esnext`?

> In TypeScript 3.9, the behavior of the TypeScript compiler controlled by module is the same with both "esnext" and "es2020" values. This behavior can change in the future, because the "esnext" option could evolve in a backwards incompatible ways, resulting in build-time or run-time errors during a TypeScript update. As a result, code can become unstable. Using the "es2020" option mitigates this risk.

[for further read](https://angular.io/guide/migration-update-module-and-target-compiler-options)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `esnext` to your --lib instead of 'es2019'

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"]
}
```

It worked for me.