# Angular split list

Tags: angular, list, typescript

I have a list looking like so

```
[[{A},{B}], {C}]
```

Is there any simple method without having to create a function that will flatten this to an array looking like so

```
[{A},{B},{C}]
```

I searched on SO but did not find anything with typescript methods.

Thanks.

Edit : A, B and C are the same types.

Comment: Please clarify: are `A`, `B`, and `C` different types or the same type?

Comment: Yes they are. I edited my post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that what you're looking for is the built-in [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
const input = [['foo', 'bar'], 'baz'];
const output = input.flat(); // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Note that you'll have to compile this with `esnext` support. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any) for more details. It also won't work out of the box on IE or Edge. If that's a problem in your use case, you'll want to use the polyfill that's shown in the MDN link above.

Alternatives exist in numerous libaries, for example, [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatten), [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten), and [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) all have an equivalent `flatten` method.