# Typescript list

Tags: angular, list, typescript, size

[image]

[image: t]

Hi all,

I have a list which I think looks like that : `[[{A},{B}],[{C}]]` with A,B and C the same type.
However, the length of that list is 0 (Array 0).

> Any reason why ? How should I deal with such a list ?

I posted today as well [Angular split list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872561/angular-split-list/54872692) however flat do nothing about that issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see any `Array(0)`, other than `__proto__`'s length (which is normal)? You should be looking at `length: 2` instead.

Comment: it shiows length 2 and 1, which is normal.

Comment: Let s say that we have D = [[{A},{B}], [{C}]]. Then somehow what I returned is D.length and it s value is 0. I think it may be types related.