# Angular: Create 2 objects from 1 objects in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, optimization

I have an array as shown below

```
 [
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "updateDate",
    "displayName": "UPDATE DATE",
    "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "uiOrder": 1,

  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "name",
    "displayName": "First Name",
    "uiControl": "TEXTBOX",
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "uiOrder": 1,
  },
]
```

I want to filter objects in this array with the property `UiControl === DATERANGE` and create 2 objects from the filtered object and also append`'FROM'` and `'TO'`  to the name and the displayname property as shown below

final output:

```
[{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "fromupdateDate",            // 'from'appended to name property
  "displayName": "FROM UPDATE DATE",   // 'FROM' appended to displayName property
  "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
  "dataType": "STRING",
  "uiOrder": 1,
 },
 {
  "id": 42,
  "name": "toupdateDate",               // 'to' appended to name property
  "displayName": "TO UPDATE DATE",      // 'TO' appended to displayName
  "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
  "dataType": "STRING",
  "uiOrder": 1,
 },
 {                                      // this object stays the same
   "id": 44,
   "name": "name",
   "displayName": "First Name",
   "uiControl": "TEXTBOX",
   "dataType": "STRING",
   "uiOrder": 1,
  }]


We can create such an array in multiple ways, but I want to find an optimized way of creating such an object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) will do what you want:

```js
const input = [{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "updateDate",
    "displayName": "UPDATE DATE",
    "uiControl": "DATERANGE",
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "uiOrder": 1,

  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "name",
    "displayName": "First Name",
    "uiControl": "TEXTBOX",
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "uiOrder": 1,
  },
];
const output = input.flatMap(v => v.uiControl === "DATERANGE" 
  ? [
      { ...v,
        name: `from${v.name}`,
        displayName: `FROM ${v.displayName}`
      },
      { ...v,
        name: `to${v.name}`,
        displayName: `TO ${v.displayName}`
      }
    ] 
  : [v]);
console.log(output);
```

Note that you'll have to compile this with `esnext` support. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any) for more details. It also won't work out of the box on IE or Edge. If that's a problem in your use case, you'll want to use a polyfill or rely on [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) + [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```
const output = input.map(v => v.uiControl === "DATERANGE" 
  ? [
      { ...v,
        name: `from${v.name}`,
        displayName: `FROM ${v.displayName}`
      },
      { ...v,
        name: `to${v.name}`,
        displayName: `TO ${v.displayName}`
      }
    ] 
  : [v])
  .reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.push(...cur), acc), []);
```