# Returning properties of array of array of values Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to know if there's a fancy way to return an array of strings created by the properties of an array of objects. The property of those objects it's also an array.

**E.g Data:**

```
[
 {
  servicesOffered: ["x","Y"]
 },
 {
  servicesOffered: ["z","w"]
 }
]
```

I tried to be fancy using the spread operator but doesn't work. I know I can iterate again the array of servicesOffered, but I don't know if there's a fancier or better way to do this.

**Code:**

```
 getServices(results: Business[]): string[] {
    return results.map(({ servicesOffered }) => {
      const t = servicesOffered;
      return ...t;
    });
  }
```

**Expected Output**

```
["x","Y","z","w"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of map:

```js
function getServices(results) {
  return results.flatMap(({ servicesOffered }) => servicesOffered);
}

const data = [{"servicesOffered":["x","Y"]},{"servicesOffered":["z","w"]}];

const result = getServices(data);

console.log(result);
```

If flatMap is not supported, you can use `Array.map()` with spread and `Array.concat()` to flatten the array:

```js
function getServices(results) {
  return [].concat(...results.map(({ servicesOffered }) => servicesOffered));
}

const data = [{"servicesOffered":["x","Y"]},{"servicesOffered":["z","w"]}];

const result = getServices(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: wow you just read my mind. I  have never seen `flatMap` before (super cool), the browser recognizes it but VS code doesn't. Is it a new method?

Comment: Indeed. You should look at the support in the supplied link. If it's not supported by your target browsers, I've added another option. You can also use a [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.flatMap).

Comment: Yes I saw the alternative, Google Chrome run it perfectly , but VS Code didn't recognize it.

Comment: See this answer about flatMap and flat with typescript - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `reduce`.

```js
let arr = [ {  servicesOffered: ["x","Y"] }, {  servicesOffered:["z","w"] }],
    result = arr.reduce((a, {servicesOffered}) => a.concat(servicesOffered), []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```