# Flatten array of arrays available in Javascript but not in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In Javascript, it is possible to flatten an array of arrays with [Array​.prototype​.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (you can test it  in Chrome's developer console) :

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = [4, 5, 6]
const arr = [a, b]
console.log(arr.flat())
```

**Output :**

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Now, if I try the same code in TypeScript, I get the following error :

> TS2339: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'number[][]'.

Why ? Is it simply not included in TypeScript ? 
It does not seem to be a recent nor non-standard feature. Is there another way to call this function ?

There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) to flatten arrays of arrays but I find them hardly readable.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any

Comment: That's in ES2019, isn't it?  Your `--lib` in [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) needs to include [the right library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L39-L133)

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Will the generated code still be compatible with odl browsers or do I need a polyfill ?

Comment: Definitely works :) I mark my own question as a duplicate of the suggested one.