# how to union/merge the array inside array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to merge or union the array of array in angular

```
const b: any = [];
b.push(
  [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-21 08:08:00" }
  ],
  [{ date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" }, { date: "2019-10-20 08:08:00" }],
  [{ date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" }, { date: "2019-12-30 08:08:00" }]
);
uniq(flatten(b, true), true, item => item.date); //error here
```

`error:Expected 1 arguments, but got 3.`

and remove the duplicate using the lodash uniqBy.

expected output:

```
[
    "2019-12-21 08:08:00",
    "2019-12-20 08:08:00",
    "2019-12-30 08:08:00"
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Underscore - uniq](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq) and [flatten](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten) to achieve this.

```
const b: any = []; b.push(   [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-21 08:08:00" }   
   ],
   [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-10-20 08:08:00" }
   ],
   [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" }, 
    { date: "2019-12-30 08:08:00" }
   ] );
_.uniq(_.flatten(b, true), true, item => item.date)
```

Result:

```
[{date:"2019-12-20 08:08:00"},
{date:"2019-12-21 08:08:00"},
{date:"2019-10-20 08:08:00"},
{date:"2019-12-30 08:08:00"}]
```

With lodash, below is the way

`_.uniqBy(_.flatten(b, item => item.date), 'date')`

Comment: can you show an out put

Comment: Copy this code, Go to https://underscorejs.org, <kbd>F12</kbd>, paste it to console and check

Comment: how to use it in lodash?

Comment: why not? I guess these functions should also work with it.

Comment: I'll try it on stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-n9uuzq?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: updated the answer for lodash

Comment: done update the answer for lodash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206415/discussion-between-abc-and-paritosh).

Comment: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type, but when i'll add to ```_.uniqBy(_.flatten(b, (item: any) => item.date), 'date')``` Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Answer (score 1):

We can use vanilla JavaScript. So what we need is:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get only unique items from array
- `flatMap` method to flat array
- `Array.from` to create array from `Map` collection

So code looks like this:

```
const result = new Map(b.flatMap(s => s).map(a => [a.date]));
let uniques = Array.from(result.keys());
```

An example:

```js
const b = [];
b.push(
  [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-12-21 08:08:00" }
  ],
  [
    { date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
    { date: "2019-10-20 08:08:00" }
  ],
  [{ date: "2019-12-20 08:08:00" },
  { date: "2019-12-30 08:08:00" }]
);

const result = new Map(b.flatMap(s => s).map(a => [a.date]));
console.log(Array.from(result.keys()));
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-n9uuzq?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @ABC yeah, it works.

Comment: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: not working....

Comment: @ABC It looks like you need to set some settings into your configuration [Typescript flatMap, flat, flatten doesn't exist on type any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any)