# How to properly flatten an stream of observables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Here's what I trying to do:

Given a paginated API, get all the resources using parallel requests.

The API returns a limited number of resources per call. So, you need to use an offset parameter to get to the next set of data until all data is extracted.

Here's my idea (but getting some warning because I'm using flat on the response), so maybe there's a better way to do this.

1. Get the total count of items.
2. Given the count and the limit, calculate how many requests are needed to get all data.
3. Trigger all requests in parallel and combine all data into a flattened array.

Here's an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/paginated-api?embed=1&file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1&devtoolsheight=100

```js
getCount().pipe(
  mergeMap(count => range(0, Math.ceil(count / limit))),
  map(offset => getDevices(offset, limit)),
  combineAll(),
).subscribe(res => {
  const a = res.flat(); // <--- warning: Property 'flat' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }[][]'.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
});
```

I feel this solution is a little hacky. It's flattening the response in the subscription. I'd like to know if there's an RXJS operator that I can use on the pipe to flatten the response, so I don't have to in the subscription?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. *What* warning?

Comment: @jonrsharpe added an example and the warning I'm getting

Comment: Then have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53556409/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's good to silence the warning. However, I feel it is a little hacky to flatten array in the subscription. I'd like to know if there's an RXJS operator that I can use on the pipe to flatten the response, so I don't have to in the subscription?

Comment: RxJS doesn't care about arrays, it deals with observables. But if you're at a point where you have working code that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: Ok, so going back to manipulating observables, how to merge/flatten multiple observables responses? I think there must an operator that does that I'm not aware of.

Comment: You are *using* one, `combineAll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every inner Observable, we need another flattening operator.

So something like this would work:

```
getCount().pipe(

  mergeMap(count => range(0, Math.ceil(count / limit))),

  mergeMap(offset => getDevices(offset, limit)),

  mergeAll(),
  toArray()

).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('result', JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

The first `mergeMap` flattens the inner `range` Observable. The second `mergeMap` flattens the `getDevices`, which I assume returns an Observable.

The `mergeAll()` merges all of the individual values, which are the objects.

The `toArray()` then adds all of the objects to a single array.

This is the result:

```
result
[{"name":"dev-1"},{"name":"dev-2"},{"name":"dev-3"},{"name":"dev-4"},{"name":"dev-5"},{"name":"dev-6"},{"name":"dev-7"},{"name":"dev-8"},{"name":"dev-9"},{"name":"dev-10"},{"name":"dev-11"},{"name":"dev-12"},{"name":"dev-13"},{"name":"dev-14"},{"name":"dev-15"},{"name":"dev-16"},{"name":"dev-17"},{"name":"dev-18"},{"name":"dev-19"},{"name":"dev-20"}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @DeborahK! Exactly what I wanted. BTW, I went to your talk in ng-conf! Definitely taking your RXJS course in Pluralsight! :)

Answer (score 0):

3 ways to do this:

Using `mergeMap`, all requests are triggered in parallel. However, the end result will be based on the order of arrival. Meaning that if your API is sorted this might break it.

```js
const getAllOffsets = () => pipe(
  mergeMap((count: number) => range(0, Math.ceil(count / limit))),
  toArray(),
  // all requests in parallel and results in order (order of creation)
  concatMap(r => forkJoin(...r.map(offset => getDevices(offset, limit)))),
  map(a => a.flat())
);
```

Using `concatMap`, this will guarantee the order. However, each request is executed one after another. This will be a performance issue

```js
const getAllOffsets2 = () => pipe(
  mergeMap((count: number) => range(0, Math.ceil(count / limit))),
  // all requests in parallel but order is not guarantee (response order)
  concatMap(offset => getDevices(offset, limit)),
  mergeAll(),
  toArray()
);
```

Finally, using `forkJoin`. This will execute all requests in parallel and keep them in the order of creation. Like `Promise.all`. This is the most optimal for getting all resources from paginated APIs.

```js
const getAllOffsets3 = () => pipe(
  mergeMap((count: number) => range(0, Math.ceil(count / limit))),
  toArray(),
  // all requests in parallel and results in order (order of creation)
  concatMap(r => forkJoin(...r.map(offset => getDevices(offset, limit)))),
  map(a => a.flat())
);
```

Full working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/paginated-api-ozcgwg?file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1&devtoolsheight=100

```js
getCount().pipe(getAllOffsets3()).subscribe(res => {
  console.log({res, size: res.length || 0});
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  // console.log('end', res.map(d => d.name));
});
```