# How to add lib es2019 to Angular project recently updated to v10, in vs code?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

My objective is a working Angular v10 project, using `.flat()` on arrays. Our team recently upgraded our Angular project to version 10. The project now, based on the Angular CLI, has the following files in the root:

1. tsconfig.base.json
2. tsconfig.json

Everything works, but our IDE (vs code), gives us the warning:

```js
Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'.ts(2339)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559473/3694288) on SO, adding `es2019` to the lib property should fix the issue. But I have added "es2019" to both tsconfig.base.json *and* tsconfig.json to no help.

Comment: Works for me (on `tsconfig.base.json`), try restarting your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but restarting Code did not help.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I already had something in "lib" so I just changed the es from 2018 to 2019:

From:

```
"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
```

To:

```
"lib": ["es2019", "dom"]
```

(And it took about 30-60 seconds before Code recognized the changes in my ts files)