# Join Map values into single string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
let urls = new Map<string, any[]>();
urls.set("1", ["param=1", "param2=2", "params3=3"]);
urls.set("2", ["param4=4", "param5=5"]);


function getUrl(): string {
  let _tmp = []; 
  urls.forEach((e) => { 
    _tmp.push(e.join("&"));
  });

  return _tmp.join("&");

}

getUrl();
```

As result I need to get one complete string: `param=1&param2=2&params3=3&param4=4&param5=5`

I dont like temprorary variable `let _tmp = [];` , how to improve this?

Comment: You can map-reduce.

Comment: How to reduce Map()?

Comment: use the array reduce method

Comment: What's the problem with the current approach? You can do `[...urls.values()].flat().join("&")` but is it really better?

Comment: @SunnyGoel Maps don't have a `.reduce()` method.

Comment: Don't forget to escape all of the values otherwise the resulting URL might be invalid given certain characters. You'd be better of using [URLSearchParams.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you ;)

```js
let urls = new Map();
urls.set("1", ["param=1", "param2=2", "params3=3"]);
urls.set("2", ["param4=4", "param5=5"]);
let result = Array.from(urls.values()).map(arr => arr.join('&')).join('&');
console.log(result);
```

You can also achieve this a bit easier using `.flat`, but then you have to add **`es2019`** to lib section of `tsconfig.json`, because `.falt` is not in the official specification. More abut this you can read here: [Typescript flatMap, flat, flatten doesn't exist on type any[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any)

```js
Array.from(urls.values()).flat().join('&')
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you need?

```js
const urls = new Map()
urls.set("1", ["param=1", "param2=2", "params3=3"])
urls.set("2", ["param4=4", "param5=5"])

const result = [...urls.values()].flat().join('&')
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'any[][]'

Comment: @CoverBase sounds like TS is not targetting ES2019.

Comment: The same problem

Comment: @CoverBase : seems to work [like that](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/dyGqYxd?editors=0011)

Comment: @CoverBase because `.flat` is not in official specification. You can try my answer if you do not want to add `.flat` && `.flatMap` to your `tsconfig.json` dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use Map of arrays, then following will work:

```js
let urls = new Map<string, any[]>();
urls.set("1", ["param=1", "param2=2", "params3=3"]);
urls.set("2", ["param4=4", "param5=5"]);

function getUrl(): string {
    const sep = '&';
    return Array.from(urls.values())
        .map((params) => {
        return params.join(sep)
    })
    .join(sep);
}

getUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can map the outer values and inside that, you can map the inner values while joining.

```js
let urls = {
  '1': [ 'param=1', 'param2=2', 'params3=3' ],
  '2': [ 'param4=4', 'param5=5' ]
}

function getUrl() {
  return Object.values(urls).map(values => values.join('&')).join('&')
}

console.log(getUrl())
```

Here is the TypeScript equivalent:

```
let urls = new Map<string, any[]>();
urls.set("1", ["param=1", "param2=2", "params3=3"]);
urls.set("2", ["param4=4", "param5=5"]);


function getUrl(): string {
    return Array.from(urls.values()).map(values => values.join('&')).join('&')
}

console.log(getUrl())
```

Comment: @Karan `flatMap` is not widely supported. Also, it doesn't matter, because we know it's only 2 levels.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl it's supported in environments that support Map objects.

Comment: @Karan and instead of `.flatMap(x => x)` you can also use `.flat()`