# How can i access values in an array of Objects using typescript with angular 9?

Tags: arrays, angular, quickbase

I am trying to retrieve values from a table in quickbase.
[image: image of quickbase table]

this is what i have so far....
**service.ts**

```typescript
    public getNativeFields(){
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("QB-Realm-Hostname", "xxxxxx.quickbase.com").set("Authorization", "QB-USER-TOKEN xxxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    
        let requestBody = {
          "from": this.someTableTableId,
          "select": [6,7]
        }
        return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/records/query?appId=${this.appId}`, requestBody, { headers })
 
    }
```

in my **component.ts** I have...

```typescript
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let list= this.apiService.getNativeFields();
        console.log("list is" );
        console.log(list);
        list.forEach(element=>{
          this.nativeVersions.push(element);
        })
        console.log("native versions");
        console.log(this.nativeVersions);
      }
```

this log returns

[image: image of array of object that was logged into console]

how do I extract the
{value:"1.0.0"} and
{value:"1.0.5"}

Comment: Hi @Kevner, the point is that `this.apiService.getNativeFields()` will return a observable to you. 
Try to do it: `this.apiService.getNativeFields().subscribe((response) => {
 console.log(response); // Verify if its return the same on your print
 response[0].data.[0][7] // {value:"1.0.0"}
 response[0].data.[0][7] // {value:"1.0.5"}
})`

Comment: @Patrick ahh yes youre right. So subscribing returns these arrays

`{data: Array(2), fields: Array(2), metadata: {…}}
data: Array(2)
0:
6: {value: "1.0.0"}
7: {value: "<p>Test</p>
↵
↵<ul>
↵ <li>test 1</li>
↵ <li>test 2</li>
↵ <li>test 3</li>
↵</ul>
↵"}
__proto__: Object
1:
6: {value: "1.0.5"}
7: {value: "<p>test</p>
↵
↵<ul>
↵ <li>test</li>
↵</ul>
↵
↵<p>test</p>
↵
↵<ul>
↵ <li>test</li>
↵</ul>
↵"}
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
fields: (2) [{…}, {…}]
metadata: {numFields: 2, numRecords: 2, skip: 0, totalRecords: 2}
__proto__: Object`

Comment: @Patrick but, `response[0].data.[0][7]` still gives me that error
`core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (current-versions.component.ts:39)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)

**Thanks for all the help so far @Patrick. I appreciate it :)

Comment: According to your return, it should be available here: `response.data[0][6]`.

Comment: @Patrick yea, that didnt work... but this did.. `response["data"][0][6]` Thanks again, though. The help was greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It should work to retrieve values:

```
this.nativeVersions[0].data[0]["6"] //{value:"1.0.0"}
this.nativeVersions[0].data[1]["6"] //{value:"1.0.5"}
```

Comment: Hey @Patrick ! thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested but i get this error




`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at CurrentVersionsComponent.ngOnInit (current-versions.component.ts:35)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12026)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13404)
    at refreshView (core.js:12035)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13458)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11729)
    at refreshView (core.js:12064)`

Answer (score 0):

Try a dynamic generation of the fields, this way you wont have to worry about which index was for `version` of `notes`

From the Object, we can see we have

```json
[
  {
     data: [...],
     fields: [...]
  }
]
```

The fields define how the data structure is, so we can generate the a simpler object through the `map` operator. See below code

```typescript
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
  list$ = this.apiService.getNativeFields();
  allVersions$ = this.list$.pipe(
    map(list =>
      (list.map(({ fields, data }) =>
        data.map(item =>
          fields.reduce((prev, next) => {
            return { ...prev, [next.label]: item[next.id]["value"] };
          }, {})
        )
      ) as any).flat()
    ),
    map(item => item.map(({ version }) => version))
  );
  ngOnInit() {
    this.allVersions$.subscribe({
      next: items => console.log(items)
    });
  }
```

[See this demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wwfe3e)

**NB** `.flat()` function is only available in `es2019`. This post will help with any challenges [Typescript flatMap, flat, flatten doesn't exist on type any[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any)