# Deno: VS Code typescript doesnt know ES6

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-next, deno

I am building an app with deno and typescript. As my IDE I'm using VS Code.

When I'm trying to use modern javascript syntax like await and flatMap VS Code underlines these statements in red and shows errors like:

> Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[]'. ts(2339)

or

> Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher. ts(1378)

but also when trying to import deno libraries:

> Cannot find module 'https://deno.land/std/fs/mod' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

How do I fix these errors? Where do they come from?

I do not have any typescript extension installed but I have the official Deno extension by denoland.

Comment: @JaredSmith I already found that too but I have no idea what the answers are talking about (I think its because they are talking about angular). Unless someone can tell me where I find my "--lib settings for TypeScript" this answer does not help me.

Comment: You set it in the compilerOptions in your project's tsconfig.json, just like everything else with configuring typescript, it has nothing to do with Angular. Then it will work and you'll get proper autocomplete and no squiggles.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jared Smith and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any) post I was able to fix the problems.

I added a tsconfig.json to the root directory of my folder and added this to it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES2020"
  }
}
```