# TypeScript- Extract values from array in array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array like that :

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "city": [{
                "name": "BERLIN",
            }
        ],
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "city": [{
                "name": "PARIS",
            }
        ],
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "city": [{
                "name": "LONDON",
            }, {
                "name": "EXETER",
            }
        ],
    }
```

And I would like extract the values below :

```
[
    {id: 1, city: {name: "BERLIN"}, 
    {id: 2, city: {name: "PARIS"},
    {id: 3, city: {name: "LONDON"},
    {id: 3, city: {name: "EXETER"} 
]
```

I tried with and two map but, I don't have the result expected.

Can you help me for this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: sorry, mistake of me, I fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this:

```js
const a = [{
  "id": 1,
  "city": [{
    "name": "BERLIN",
  }],
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "city": [{
    "name": "PARIS",
  }],
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "city": [{
    "name": "LONDON",
  }, {
    "name": "EXETER",
  }],
}];

const result = a.flatMap(({id, city}) => city.map(c => ({id, city: c})));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have flatmap in my angular project...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any).