# Remove one level from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove the indexes of an array in the easiest and most efficient possible way. This is the array like:

Having this array (see snipet):

```js
let arr = [];
arr.push([{id:1}]);
arr.push([{id:2}, {id: 3}]);
arr.push([{id:4}]);
console.log(arr)
```

the expected result is an array that joins all the objects into one same index.

```
[
{id: 1},
{id: 2},
{id: 3},
{id: 4}
]
```

If I iterate every element on the array and add every object to a new array I can get the result I'm expecting but there must be a function or something that simplifies de code..

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const newArr = arr.map(e => e[0]);`

Comment: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is! is the `flat()` method (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat))

```js
let arr = [
[{id:1}],
[{id:2}],
[{id:3}],
[{id:4}]
];
console.log(arr.flat())
```

It works also for more annidated sublist, passing a `depth` parameter.

For those using **typescript** remember to add `es2019` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any).

Comment: It's not working on angular with typescript as it is not recognized in the default compiler, I finally had to use `arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])` but still your function is what I was looking for and im going to accept as a valid answer, could you add this code below into the answer for people who is using typescript? thanks!

Comment: @David you can use `flat` method also with typescript. See my edit.