# how to access nested field in object in Javascript?

Tags: typescript

i want to access the field names of an object nested within another object. In this example i want to map through user object. i tried to map through message ojbect and store it in a variable. then tried to map again but its giving an error saying `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.`

18 console.log(message[0].message.id);

```
 { message:
     { id: '0301939f-59b5-45f0-bc24-89a4d6840579',
       text: 'Everyone is here with the intention to improve.',
       html: '<p>Everyone is here with the intention to improve.</p>\n',
       type: 'regular',
       user: [Object],
       attachments: [Array],
       latest_reactions: [],
       own_reactions: [],
       reaction_counts: null,
       reaction_scores: {},
       reply_count: 0,
       cid: 'messaging:3',
       created_at: '2021-07-08T20:23:02.354861Z',
       updated_at: '2021-07-08T20:23:02.354861Z',
       shadowed: false,
       mentioned_users: [],
       silent: false,
       pinned: false,
       pinned_at: null,
       pinned_by: null,
       pin_expires: null,
       channel: [Object],
       title: 'Welcome to your pod d8jqzxzxp8@privaterelay.appleid.com!' } } ]
3
```

user object

```
{ id: 'masterHealthBot',
  role: 'admin',
  created_at: '2021-06-21T15:12:20.226915Z',
  updated_at: '2021-07-08T21:11:34.32916Z',
  banned: false,
  online: false,
  name: 'MasterHealth Bot' }
3


const message =  response.results.map(({ message }) => message.user);

console.log(message[0].id); // not working
console.log(message.map(({user})-> user.id)) give user undefined error
```

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks for your time.

Comment: What's your expected output? _"map through message object and store it in a variable"_ doesn't make much sense. Can't you simply assign/copy the object to a new variable? Also, you can't use `map` on an object unless you use something like `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, or `Object.entries` to get an array from the object.

Comment: Also `message` isn't an array so `message[0]` won't work.

Comment: i need to get d from user object

Comment: @LeoBogod  from what I  understand from the comments in the answers, messages is an array of objects, and user is an array objects. Don't you think that it might've been a good idea to 'share ' that with us ? Please learn how to ask questions properly. `i need to get d from user object` has nothing to do with what you are actually trying to do

Comment: @MihaiT you could have figured this out basing on this piece of code: `response.results.map`

Comment: @YuriyYakym Really ? how so ? Couldn't it be that the OP doesn't know the difference between object and array of objects ? and array methods ? Like another user ( Andy ) pointed out that `map` is an array method and it won't work on object `messages` . Also, it's not my job to 'figure out' what the OP wants and doesn't want. It's his job to be clear in his explanation

Comment: @MihaiT Yes, quite easily. If `response.results` was an object, OP would receive an error `.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what exactly you are trying to do. But if `user` is nested inside `message` . Why don't you use `message.user` to get the User object?  `map` is an array method the same goes for using `[0]` ( index selector ) .

EDIT: user is in fact an array of objects

So you could do something like this:

```js
const message = {
  id: 'messageId1234',
  user: [{
    id: 'masterHealthBot',

  },
  {
    id: 'masterHealthBot2',

  }]
}
const users = message?.user;

users.map(user => console.log(user.id))
```

Comment: i just need to get  all id value from user object

Comment: @LeoBogod and ? doesn't my answer provide that ?

Comment: well the answer just loops through entire object i only need id

Comment: how do i access the id field , user is an array of objects. in my case (message[0]) will get me only the first array within the object

Comment: Please be more clear. In your question you show the user as an object. Not as an array of objects. In my answer, the line  `console.log(user.id)` returns just the ID  . So, to be clear, the message object contains some key-value pairs and also an `user` key that is an array of objects ? eg `message :  { id : 12121 , user: [{ id: user1}, { id: user2 }] }` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get single user id, you can do `messages[0].user[0].id`.

If you want to get all the ids, consider using this code:

```js
const messages = response.results;
const allUserIds = messages.flatMap((message) => {
  return message.user.map((user) => user.id);
});
console.log(allUserIds );
```

or using `Array.prototype.reduce` if `Array.prototype.flatMap` is unavailable:

```js
const messages = response.results;
const allUserIds = messages.reduce((result, message) => {
  const messageUsersIds = message.user.map((user) => user.id);
  return [...result, ...messageUsersIds];
}, []);
console.log(allUserIds );
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use `message[0]`. Optional chaining won't work here.

Comment: i just need to get all id value from user object

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding user is an array of ojbects

Comment: getting an error Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.

   return message.user.map((user) => user.id);

Comment: Adding typing should be already up to you. If you want to test the code just do the following: `messages.flatMap((message: any) => ...` and `message.user.map((user: any) => ...`

Comment: Also please use proper tags next time. You are using TypeScript, whereas you tagged your question with `javascript`

Comment: ok im pretty new to typescrit so appreciat the help . Getting error saying TypeError: messages.flatMap is not a function.

Comment: does my node version not support flatmap? any alternatives to flatmap?

Comment: @LeoBogod to use new features configure your tsconfig file. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any

Comment: i did that but still get the error. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: messages.flatMap is not a function
    at GetMessages.getAllMessages (/home/kk/mh-api/src/components/chat/test.ts:21:29)

Comment: "lib": [ "DOM" ,"ES2019"]

Comment: Why use flatMap in the first place ? `messages` is just a big object, right ? not an array , right ?

Comment: array of objects

Comment: @LeoBogod updated the code with reduce instead of flatMap