# How to split a part from a string when a special character is found

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of string which looks like this:

```
ErrStr = [
\\abc\def\ghi;  ,
\\klm\nop\qrs;
]
```

So, this array of strings will be dynamic, so what I want to extract is only the `abc` and `klm` from this array.

This piece of code is what joins the strings after filtering from the data:

```
let errorArr = filteredError.map(a => a.ErrStr.split('\\\\', '')).join('')
```

I tried the above code, it cuts the `\\` and replaces with `,` but I am not able to figure out how do I remove the 2nd and 3rd part of the string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ErrStr = [\\abc\def\ghi;  ,\\klm\nop\qrs;]` but that's an invalid array - since those are not strings.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that's a JSON string that I parsed and put into an array to get the desired strings to display

Answer (score 0):

[Backslash in an Escape character in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/383904) and has special meaning. To literally use it you need to, well, escape it beforehand with another backslash

```js
const str1 = "\a";
console.log(str1);  // "a"    Where's my backslash?
const str2 = "\\a";
console.log(str2);  // "\a"   Aha, here it is
```

Therefore, first make sure your array has Strings (which currently what you provided are not strings therefore it's an invalid JSON)

And use:

```js
const arr = [
  "\\\\abc\\def\\ghi;",
  "\\\\klm\\nop\\qrs;",
];

const codes = arr.map(s => /(?<=^\\\\)[^\\]+/.exec(s)).flat()
console.log(codes); // ["abc", "klm"]
```

Overview example on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8ClRm6/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting this error on `flat` : `Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'RegExpExecArray[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.`  Any idea what needs to be changed. I am not allowed to change any library

Comment: @pranami as far as I can see Array.prototype.flat() is supported by all major browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat - The error is quite strange though, since in the code we're applying `.flat()` on an .map() mapped Array, not on regexp. Seems to me like a Typescript issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/typescript-flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any