# How to flatten array or reduce to get true values?

Tags: typescript

I have the following array of object. I want to get total count where properties are true. i.e in this case total enabled is 5

```
let data = 
[
    {
        comment: true,
        attachment: true,
        actionPlan: true
    },
    {
        whenValue: '',
        comment: true,
        attachment: false,
        actionPlan: true
    }
]
```

I tried  something below but it didnt worked.

```
const countObj = questionAttributes.questionMandatoryOptions.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return {
        //want to get properties having true values
    };
});
```

For single item in array i can achieve with followign:

```
const total =
            options[0];
        const totalelections = Object.values(
            total
        ).filter((v) => v).length;
```

Comment: `I tried something below but it didnt work.` I can hardly call an empty function an attempt at solving the problem... I wish putting my expected output in a comment would get me the expected output, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alresdy found the solution for a single element, so all you really need
to do is to iterate over every element in your `data` and increase a counter with the result of

`Object.values(item).filter((v) => v).length;`

```
let data = 
[
    {
        comment: true,
        attachment: true,
        actionPlan: true
    },
    {
        whenValue: '',
        comment: true,
        attachment: false,
        actionPlan: true
    }
]

function countTrueProperties(a_data: any[]): number {
    let count = 0;
    for(const item of a_data){
        count += Object.values(item).filter((v) => v).length;
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(countTrueProperties(data));
```

[Demo playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQLACgDa6I4gb21yIGMB7AW3JADswAuCMAJwFcQAaQonOeYgCyq0GzNpzTdcMYmACWpagAVgMaiNYguEAL7iiBCZIgB3fjQBqMYGwYByW3qNlKNeow2PJvaYNcMAZlYAzhxaRNJyCsqq6mxa2ugAuujo-izUMvLUEGTpYAAqGopMpAAOIExyIEEAFDAA+rDwDKoAnhiJAJQM1CzkAEYV+FqgkLm0SBAADADcWv6kTDVk1EGQsmAg5BCk-hANTTCdBkY5pHkQANTIAPL9AFYgMgB0AG5WbLUbW53P-rLATZLGqvTpIAB8EFBz1A1AA5mB+HNDDgEiiIExwCwmNlxmBkWj0CsgqRQDDSHDludaIU2MUyhUqrVDp1OjMgA)

Answer (score 0):

Will work for the following ts configs: `"target": "es2019"`, or if `lib` contains `"esnext"`.

Details: [flatMap, flat, flatten doesn't exist on type any[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556409/flatmap-flat-flatten-doesnt-exist-on-type-any/53559473#53559473)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
let data = [{
    comment: true,
    attachment: true,
    actionPlan: true
  },
  {
    whenValue: '',
    comment: true,
    attachment: false,
    actionPlan: true
  }
];

const countObj = data
  .map(x => Object.values(x)) // [[true, true, true], ["", true, false, true]]
  .flatMap(x => x) // [true, true, true, "", true, false, true]
  .filter(x => x === true) // [true, true, true, true, true]
  .length; // 5

console.log(countObj); // 5
```

[image: Edit TypeScript (forked)]

Comment: Getting flatMap does not exist on type any[][]

Comment: my tsconfig looks like

    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]

Comment: Your example doesn't compile in a simple [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQNoG8CwAoCuIGMB7AW2JADswAuCMAJwFcQAabPCOefACzMpvpNWOPDHxgAloXIAFYDHIDGINhAC+w3JhG4A7twoA1GMCY0A5Oc14ipCtVrLruTmN72aAMxMBnFqpdxKVl5RUcmVTVsAF0AbmxsInIfSCIGSgB5ACMAKyRoOBhVADpiGAAHAAoADyQAPghsnJBxYoA3EyYfGoBKHogAegHUFEEWcPGx6OZUACJZmbGZ72A-ReVo6JLPeTAAWQqa+ohq-qHUJYn1oQh56-GVtYmtkWLPCWAwEDojxAbaxCAiZnYajJxXCGXKYlUDkADmYG4sUGwwArAksEkfIRQMVgIQ4ZU0plcj1kedUUA)

Comment: questionAttributes.questionMandatoryOptions is an object array

Comment: Unfortunately i can't switch to 'es2019'. can u pls provide some other solution? Thanks